Are finitely generated nilpotent-by-cyclic groups residually finite?
I would like to check whether finitely generated nilpotent-by-cyclic groups are residually finite.
Here are some results I found online:

Every finitely generated nilpotent-by-cyclic group is an ascending HNN extension of a finitely generated nilpotent group.

The HNN extension of a finitely generated nilpotent group might not be residually finite.


However, I don't think every HNN extension of a finitely generated nilpotent group can be written as a finitely generated nilpotent-by-cyclic group?
Has this result been studied before?

What does "nilpotent-by-cyclic" mean? There are two possible answers, and about half of the mathematicians in the world would give one and the other half the other. So how can the reader be expected to know?

I thought $G$ is nilpotent-by-cyclic if there exists a nilpotent group $N$ such that   $G/N\cong \mathbb{Z}$?

But surely $G/N$ could also be a finite cyclic group?

Oh yes, thank you for pointing that out! I will be more careful next time.

Let $N$ be a finitely generated, non-abelian, nilpotent group. Then the wreath product
$$N \wr \mathbb{Z} \cong \left(\bigoplus_{\mathbb{Z}} N\right) \rtimes \mathbb{Z} $$
is a finitely generated nilpotent-by-cyclic group.
But a wreath product $G \wr H$ with $G$ non-abelian and $H$ infinite is never residually finite.
This follows from the following characterisation by Gruenberg [1]: a wreath product $G \wr H$ is residually finite if and only if either $G$ is residually finite and $H$ is finite, or $G$ is abelian and residually finite and $H$ is residually finite. Or, if you prefer a more direct approach, in [2] Bradford proves that $A_5 \wr \mathbb{Z}$ is not residually finite, but you can replace $A_5$ by any non-abelian group in the proof.
[1] Gruenberg, K. W., Residual properties of infinite soluble groups, Proc. Lond. Math. Soc., III. Ser. 7, 29-62 (1957). ZBL0077.02901.
[2] Bradford, H. When are wreath products Hopfian?. Lightning talk at the YGGT X conference, Newcastle (2021).
